# Overwatch: pixelation issue

Tags: overwatch

I've just downloaded Overwatch (from game disc) and started it up. Then, I noticed the graphics quality was **HORRIBLE**. Everything was pixelated, and very ugly. I tried changing the graphics quality in the menu, and changing my screen resolution in-game. My resolution is 1280x720.

[image: Overwatch Pixelation Screenshot]
<sub>[Original Image](https://imgur.com/keLyyRh)</sub>

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? What resolution are you using?

Comment: Can you screenshot the video settings?

Comment: It's better to use the post's image utility than a third party image.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't looks like 720p. What is your setting for "render scale"? If it is not 100% try setting it to this and tell me if it helps! http://i.imgur.com/jRkgt0m.png

Comment: After installing from the disc you still need to download a lot of data for the game. It may be that you can play with low resolution until the game has all data/textures/etc. to change to full resolution.

Answer (score 16):

This might be caused by the "Render Scale" setting.

From the main menu, click `OPTIONS`, then `ADVANCED` and then set `RENDER SCALE` to 100%.

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly the cause, but it's worth noting that if the render scale defaults as low as it did for Superbear it's probably for good reason-- raising the render scale can have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: @Passage Setting the render scale to < 100% has basically the same effect as using a lower resolution, except it requires extra GPU cycles to do the scaling.  I don't know why it's even an option.

Comment: Right, but let's be honest, reducing render scale results in the worst possible picture, beating any other settings in terms of crappification. Just set it to 100% and reduce other options like post-effects, motion blur, bloom, reflections and anti-aliasing.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, Except you can play as windowed full-screen with render scale. That's not possible if you use the resolution approach.

Comment: @WilliamMariager: Windowed fullscreen does have a small performance penalty compared to regular fullscreen (specifically, your window has to go through the OS's window compositing layer), so you should probably switch to the latter before you try to play with resolution and scaling.

Comment: @Kevin, Definitely. But if you want to improve performance and keep it windowed full-screen, render-scale does have a place.

Comment: Even with all my graphics settings at their absolute minimum ("Low" or even "Off"), I can't manage 30 fps unless I'm at 50% render scale. At 75% my fps drops to ~16, and the game goes from looking horrible to being unplayable. So it is definitely a useful setting.